# Guitar Hero III with keyboard only

Tags: guitar-hero-3

I want to play Guitar Hero III in a notebook, without mouse and guitar. I'm having no success to config for keyboard only. It always requires a key pressed and left button click to make a note. I need a config that is similar to joypad version of PS2/PS3 game, but for keyboard. In other words, when I press a key, it should make a note without a mouse click. If I keep the key pressed, it should maker a long note.

If you know something such as a virtual, keyboard based guitar, or a config tip, please tell me.

Thanks!

Comment: This may or may not be what you are looking for: [FretsOnFire](http://fretsonfire.sourceforge.net/) is an open source Guitar Hero Clone that is designed to be used with a keyboard. You can also get the songs from Guitar Hero III if you search for them and have the rights (licenses) for these songs. Basically you need to provide the mp3. IMHO Guitar Hero III with a guitar is a better choice than anything that involves a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

This would go against the way the game is written - you are supposed to press a button to emulate the picking action, and use another button to denote which fret is selected.

You could do it though, and the simplest way would be to look at using macros which will trigger a mouse click every time you press a key. My Logitech gaming keyboard comes with software which appears to do this

Answer (score 1):

Are you on an emulator? If so, is the controller set to a GH controller, or a normal one? My guess is that if set to a normal controller, it should automatically do the same as on the console.

The only other thing I can think of is setting up macros to keys: left mouse click happens at the same time as a keyboard click. However, I'm sure you'll run into problems with multi-key clicks, considering you'll be left clicking several times at once. I don't know your keyboard lag, so I could be wrong about the multi-key problem.

Sorry I could not give you a straight answer; I simply do not know what you're using to play the game on.